# SQL - how to get data from two tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have these tables:

### table_a

```
user_id
article_id
created_at
```

### articles

```
user_id
created_at
...
```

I need to obtain all rows from both tables for the respective user (lets say **user_id=1**) and sorted them by the column `created_at`. How to do that?

I have tried to do it this way:

```
Model.find_by_sql('SELECT table_a.* FROM table_a JOIN articles ON articles.user_id = 1 WHERE table_a.user_id = 1')
```

But this query won't work.

Comment: `ON articles.user_id = table_a.user_id` You should tell how you join the tables

Comment: Please define `won't work` and give examples.  Unexpected data, error messages, every time you run it the power in your office goes out and a purple goblin steals your mouse and keyboard?

Comment: If I think about the query now, the `JOIN` probably is not needed there... I just need to get all rows from both tables with `user_id=1`

Comment: @user984621 I don't know your business model but usually you got `User<-->UserArticles<-->Articles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give a try to following query:
`SELECT table_a.*, articles.*
FROM table_a JOIN articles ON articles.user_id = table_a.user_id 
WHERE table_a.user_id = 1
ORDER BY table_a.created_at ASC;`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT table_a.* ,articles.*
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN articles ON articles.user_id = table_a.user_id 
WHERE table_a.user_id = 1
ORDER BY table_a. created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  table_a.*
FROM 
 table_a
JOIN 
 articles 
ON 
 articles.user_id = table_a.user_id 
WHERE 
 table_a.user_id = 1
ORDER BY
 table_a.created_at ASC;
```